# Inject a merged list of beans within @Configuration

Tags: java, spring

First, let me introduce a few simple classes and interface to be able to describe my problem.

```
interface Basic { void foo(); }
interface Extended extends Basic { void bar(); }

class BasicService {
  @Inject
  List<Basic> basics;

  void execute() {
    basics.forEach(Basic::foo);
  }
}

class ExtendedService {
  @Inject
  List<Extended> extendeds;

  void execute() {
    extendeds.forEach(Extended::bar);
  }
}

@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {
  // Assume, that Basic1 and Basic2 are implementations of Basic and
  // Extended1 is an implementation of Extended
  @Bean
  public Basic basic1() {
    return new Basic1();
  }
  @Bean
  public Basic basic2() {
    return new Basic2();
  }
  @Bean
  public List<Extended> extendeds() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Extended1("0"), new Extended1("1"), new Extended1("2"));
  }

  @Bean
  public BasicService basicService() {
    return new BasicService();
  }
  @Bean
  public ExtendedService extendedService() {
    return new ExtendedService();
  }
}
```

I have two services that act on different level of abstraction. My problem is that I'm failing to find a way how I can inject all beans that implement the `Basic` interface in my `BasicService`. With the current implementation it only injects all `Extended` implementations, because I have a factory bean method that has a return type of `List` in its method signature.

I can not change the bean configuration in a way that all `Extended` beans have their own factory methods, because in my real code the number of `Extended` implementations is dynamically computed on runtime...

Is there a way I can configure Spring, so that it merges all beans with `Basic` and `List<Basic>` together in 1 big list that I can use in my `BasicService`?

Comment: AFAIK Spring should be able to inject multiple beans of the same type into a collection of that type, i.e. `@Autowired private List<Basic> basics;` not sure though if this also works with `@Inject`

Comment: `@Autowired` and `@Inject` are synonyms in this context. And usually it is possible to inject a `List<Basic>`. The problem is the factory bean method that has `List<Extended>` as a signature...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding generic bean definitions for the `Extended` implementations. This can be done by adding a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` implementation to the `@Configuration` class as follows:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public static ExtendedBeanFactory extendedBeanFactory() {
    return new ExtendedBeanFactory();
  }
}

class ExtendedBeanFactory implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {
  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
      beanDefinition.setBeanClass(Extended1.class);
      ConstructorArgumentValues args = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
      args.addGenericArgumentValue(Integer.toString(i));
      beanDefinition.setConstructorArgumentValues(args);
      registry.registerBeanDefinition("extended_" + i, beanDefinition);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    // noop
  }
}
```

This has the advantage, that consumer classes can simply inject a list of `Basic` or a list of `Extended` as the code from the question does.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether there is a way to solve this implicitly, since Spring tries to find the best match, which the List bean seems to be (have you tried generics, e.g., `List<? extends Basic>` ?).

But you could do it programmatically, by getting the bean definitions from the [ApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansOfType-java.lang.Class-):

```
public BasicService(@Inject ApplicationContext ctx) {
    Map<String, ? extends Basic> basicMap = ctx.getBeansOfType(Basic.class);
    Map<String, Collection<? extends Basic>> basicCollectionMap = ctx.getBeansofType(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(Collection.class, Basic.class));

    // Now merge
    Collection<? extends Basic> basics = basicMap.values();
    basicCollectionMap.values().stream().map(l -> basics.addAll(l));
}
```

I just typed this here, so I hope there aren't any obvious errors.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I solved it in a different way that is easier for consumer classes.